Error importing .emof file into Cameo System Modeler
When I try to import a .xmi file into Cameo Systems Modeler. I save the .xmi file as a .emof and try to imort the emof file I get an Error saying "Bad xmi or mof namespaces for emof/cmof import." I would like to know if anybody has any insight into how to troubleshoot this or insight into what are probable causes for the error and how to resolve it.
Thanks
I've tried importing the XMI directly in Cameo but it opens an empty project with none of the project details. I tried following these steps as well and see the error mentioned above https://docs.nomagic.com/display/MD190/Importing+projects+from+Ecore+files
